# Set item width and height in Gridview Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have some trouble to set height and width of the elevated button inside Gridview. Elevated Button is the child of the Gridview, and I want to make the button's width to wrap the content of the text.

[image]

Here is my code for the GridView.

```
Widget _gridView (Schedule schedule) {
  return GridView.builder(
    itemCount: schedule.workingHour.length,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: schedule.workingHour.length,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return
      ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text( schedule.workingHour[index].startHour +" - "+ schedule.workingHour[index].endHour));
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Try This one

```
Widget _gridView (Schedule schedule) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double itemHeight = (size.height - 100) / 2;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
    GridView.builder(
        itemCount: schedule.workingHour.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: itemWidth / itemHeight,
                ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text( schedule.workingHour[index].startHour +" - "+ schedule.workingHour[index].endHour));
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, can we make it fit horizontally instead of vertically? Try your code but it fit vertically. What I mean is become a normal button where its height is smaller than its width

Comment: Did you mean you want 1 button per row??

Comment: No, I mean 2 button per row, but with full text horizontally